# Historicize a table historicized wrong in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-update

Suppose I have the following wrong historic data in my table:

```
ID     DATE START      DATE END
1      2020-10-16     2020-12-11
1      2020-11-09     2021-01-02     
1      2020-12-11     2021-01-19
1      2021-01-02     2020-12-11
1      2021-01-19     2050-12-31
```

What I want is:

```
ID     DATE START      DATE END
1      2020-10-16     2020-11-09
1      2020-11-09     2020-12-11     
1      2020-12-11     2021-01-02
1      2021-01-02     2021-01-19
1      2021-01-19     2050-12-31
```

The last record must be closed by "2050-12-31' and every new **Date Start** is the Date End of the previous record .

Suppose I have this situation for thousand of records so I can't just do simple updates.

Thanks very much for everyone could help me.

Comment: If you need to update your data, your need to use an update statement. build a query which corrects the data, then turn it into an update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below script-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c50ebc01c7881add19768417b922f16)

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by DATE_START) rn,
    * 
    from your_table_name
)


select 
a.id,
a.date_start,
case when b.date_start is null then a.date_end else b.date_start end date_end 
from cte a
left join cte b on a.rn = b.rn-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple LEAD() function will do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp(ID,[DATE START],[DATE END]) VALUES 
(1,'2020-10-16','2020-12-11'),
(1,'2020-11-09','2021-01-02'),     
(1,'2020-12-11','2021-01-19'),
(1,'2021-01-02','2020-12-11'),
(1,'2021-01-19','2050-12-31')


SELECT ID,[DATE START], 
LEAD([DATE START], 1, '12/31/2050') OVER(ORDER BY ID,[DATE START]) [DATE END]
FROM #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` in an `update` as:

```
with toupdate as (
      select h.*,
             lead(date_start, 1, '2050-12-31') over (partition by id order by date_start) as next_date_start
      from historic h
     ) 
update toupdate
    set date_end = next_date_start
    where date_end <> next_date_start;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=84dd412152933f4f739e9a2e4ac43108) is a db<>fiddle.